# Search term to url

Tags: html, var

I am trying to make a search engine "comparer." By that I mean I am trying to make a local website that takes a search term and makes it into a clickable search engine URL (google, bing, yahoo, etc). I'm starting with Google. The search term needs to go after https://www.google.com/search?q= I don't know how to add the userSearch onto the end of the URL and make the URL into a clickable link. I'm not even sure that I'm gathering the search term correctly.

```html
<!-- Enter search term -->
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            <p>
              <label>Search Here! (please, no spaces)</label>
              <input type = "text"
                     id = "userSearch"
                     var = term
 />
            </p>

          </fieldset>
        </form>



<var> gURL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + userSearch </var>


<script type="text/javascript">
    <var> searchTerm = "userSearch"; </var>
    <var> gURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + 'searchTerm'; </var>

    document.getElementById("gURL").src = url;
</script>


<!-- Search URL results -->


        <h3>Results</h3>
        <fieldset>
        <h4 style="text-align:left;"><a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=">Google.com </a>
```

If you can help, thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: try looking into event listeners.  You'll have to hijack the submit button to find the text input (probably by id), get the text from it, and then append it to your url.  Just in general, you should probably spend some more time on a simpler project.  A click counter (for instance) would teach you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the click counter. I did accomplish what I was trying to do just a little bit before you responded, but I do appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I used a button and Jquery - but is this what you are trying to do?

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#userSearch').click(function() {
    var fromForm =  "<br>" + '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q="' + 
        $('#searchField').val() + ">" + 'https://www.google.com/search?q="' +$('#searchField').val() + '</a>';

    $('#outPut').append(fromForm);

  });

});     
</script>
</head>
<body>


<br>
<!-- Enter search term -->
<form>
          <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>

                 <label>Search Here! (please, no spaces)</label> <input type='text' id='searchField' placeholder="Search">
</fieldset>
</form>
                    <button id='userSearch'>Search</button>

<br>
<div id='outPut'>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my comparer using some different code using multiple guides, but I do really appreciate your feedback. I am putting my code up on a Weebly website ( [Click here](https://www.secentral.weebly.com) ) and my goal is to make it a tool that makes it easy to search from different engines. It is mostly just for personal use, but I have it set up where others could find it helpful and useful.

I used this code:

```
    <!-- Enter search term -->
<div>
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="512" id="searchTxt" class="searchField" float: center; display: block;/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //creates a listener for when you press a key
        window.onkeyup = keyup;

        //creates a global Javascript variable
        var inputTextValue;

        function keyup(e) {
          //setting your input text to the global Javascript Variable for every key press
          inputTextValue = e.target.value;

          //listens for you to press the ENTER key, at which point your web address will change to the one you have input in the search box
          if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            window.location = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + inputTextValue;
          }
        }
</script>
```

Thank you for all your guy's help, and I will definitely continue learning.